# Ubuntu desktop, wildcard nofile not working

Tags: 18.04, security, desktop-environments, ulimit, resource-limiting

I've tried setting the file limit to 32000 on ubuntu desktop for normal users by adding the following lines:

```
* soft nofile 32000
* hard nofile 32000
```

To: `/etc/security/limits.conf`

But, even after rebooting, my normal user still has the default limits (as given by ulimit -Sn and ulimit -Hn)

Adding the same thing for the root user:

```
root soft nofile 32000
root hard nofile 32000
```

Increased the nr just fine and doing the same thing on Ubuntu server always worked, what is the difference between server and desktop that is causing this bug ? And how do I get around it ?

The version is 18.0.4 (latest LTS)

Comment: See if this helps: https://superuser.com/questions/1200539/cannot-increase-open-file-limit-past-4096-ubuntu